# Getting size of array at runtime

Tags: c, pointers

I have written a function to read a buffer which contains the details of hardware used. Now the size of buffer depends on the hardware. Is there any way to check before reading the buffer the size of buffer so that i do not access any illegal location and avoid segmentation fault? Or before reading any location is it possible to see if I am accessing valid location?

Comment: can you provide us with more details on the buffer?

Comment: what `type` of buffer it is ?

Comment: No, user needs to store the size information(with dynamic arrays)May be linked list type structure
would be helpful. However it would be good if you share your relevant code snippet and what you did
and what you want to achieve?

Comment: This question is not possible to answer without guessing, because we have to know something about the buffer and the hardware to answer it.

Comment: its a normal int buf[] but the size of it would depend upon the hardware, means the specifications of the hardware. Just like reading a configuration page for any hardware.

Comment: There is no common "configuration page for hardware" standard. You have to provide more details.

Comment: Lets say the page contains the info about events occuring on a particular register of hardware. Now the event info is stored in a buffer whose size dynamically increases when another event comes. Now if I have to read the buffer to know the events what should be the size I should access so no illegal memory is accessed.

Comment: C standard provides no such info. You have to know the size. Either you can find it in the hardware manual, *or* hardware has some register which you can read the size from, *or* size of the event is stored to the event data.

Comment: Isn't there any way by which i can know before accessing any location that it is an illegal access or not in C?

Answer (score 0):

**Methode 1**:
If you don't know the buffer size, first ask the size of buffer every time. Then allocate the size using `malloc`. After using it `free` it.

**Methode 2**:
At least you have an idea about maximum size how much it will take. allocate MAX_BUFF_SIZE statically.

If you don't like above two procedures the do like below.

**Methode 3**:
Sender know how much size he is sending. Fix a limited size to transfer at a time, and send one by one.

```
Eg: Fixed transfer size = 10bytes. //both sender and receiver have an idea
    message size to send = 50bytes.  //sender have idea but receiver don't know.

   struct my_struct {
                 int transaction_no;
                 char buf[SIZE];
                 int total_messages;
                 int current_message_no;
    };
```

so sender splits his data into 5 packets(each one 10bytes). send each packet one by one.

so receiver checks the incoming packets and again reconstruct the data.

I think first two methods are better than this.